# Can't make jQuery and Ajax form submit work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm really new to web programming. I'm trying to make a form post and get the callback.

I'm trying to use this plugin here: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

But when I call the:  `$("#my_form").ajaxSubmit(options);`  Nothing happens..

**What I have done so far:**

I have this form

```
  <form method="post" id="my_form" action="record.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    // stuff inside..

    <input type="button" id = "recordDatabase" value="Rcord on Database" />

  </form>
```

And I have this script:

```
 <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
      var options = 
      {

         beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback
         success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback
      };

      $("#recordDatabase").click(function()
      {
         alert('About to submit: \n\n');
         $("#my_form").ajaxSubmit();
         alert('submited: \n\n');
         return false;
       });
 });
```

Finally my two functions are:

```
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) 
    {
            // formData is an array; here we use $.param to convert it to a string to display it
            var queryString = $.param(formData);
            alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
            return true;
    }
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
    {
        alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText +
            '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
    }
```

I´m doing exactly like the example on the site(http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit), but it doesn´t work.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: check error in console?!

Comment: github is not a CDN ?

Comment: Is that a question adeneo? I'm really noob at php. That line is there because I think is the source for the ajaxSubmit method. isn't that the way it works? I tried creating my own js file putting in local host and referencing the same way, but no luck.

Comment: Your `options` object is probably going to need to make its way into your plugin call `$("#my_form").ajaxSubmit(options);`

Comment: Even with the $("#my_form").ajaxSubmit(options); Still not working..

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a little vague.  Can you be more specific?  Do you get errors in the JavaScript console?  When you submit the form with the network tab open in your dev tools, does it log any activity?

Comment: The .ajaxForm method prepares the form to be handled by the plugin, it does not submit the form as your code seems think (documentation here: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api). Remove the click handler.

Comment: @76484 - He's not calling `.ajaxForm()`, he's calling `.ajaxSubmit()`, which *does* submit the form.

Comment: @gilly3 I'm working locally, and I'm using phpStorm just to edit the file, and then saving and running on my browser. So I dont have a JavaScript console. By "not working" I mean the first alert on top of the  ".ajaxSubmit()"  line display a message and the second ( before the ajaxSubmit() ) don't, so I  think is the ajaxSubmit fault.

Comment: @gilly3 another thing is that, if the ajaxSubmit were working, it should call the showRequest function before submiting, showing me another alert, and that is not happening.

Comment: @gilly3 Thank you gilly !!!! I could make the php storm debug the javascript.  The error is: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit' Maybe that means I'm not referencing my plugin correctly right?

Comment: Your browser has a JavaScript console.  Hit F12.

Comment: Sounds like the plugin isn't loading.  Have you included jQuery on the page more than once?

Comment: Yes! I have done this: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

And then myPlugin :   <script src="http://localhost/js/jqueryPlugin.js"></script>   is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hotlink to the jQuery plugin on Git. Try downloading the plugin and saving it as a JS file in your application web root.

Comment: Then I need to reference it locally? ( "localhost/jquery.min.js ")

Can I just create a new file and copy the js content into it and save it as a js right?

Comment: Yes you can create a new file in your text editor or IDE, copy and paste the source code into it, and save is as a .js file. I would save it to a js folder in your project's web root. Then you can use a relative path in your HTML like "js/myfile.js." Have you checked in the Network tab in Chrome developer tools or Firefox to see if the scripts are loading properly? If you see 200 status you they were downloaded successfully. If you see 404 they were not.

Comment: Nice catch Neil, in status it is written: "(failed)
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"  I'm going to try to figure that out. But if you have any idea let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed that, it is showing 302 status ( Not modified) which I think is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not referencing your scripts correctly.  According to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794540/cant-make-jquery-and-ajax-form-submit-work#comment34760951_22794540), you have included your scripts like this:

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="localhost/js/jqueryPlugin.js"></script>
```

These are relative URLs.  The browser will request the resources from your site by tacking on those relative URLs to the end of the current directory.

Suppose this page is at `http://localhost/myapp/mypage.html`.  The browser will look for your script files at:

```
http://localhost/myapp/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
http://localhost/myapp/localhost/js/jqueryPlugin.js
```

These URLs probably don't exist.  Maybe your browser is smart enough to recognise "ajax.googleapis.com" as a domain name and request the data from the domain, but it's less likely that it will recognize "localhost" as a domain.

Add `//` to the beginning of the URL.  This is a "Schema-relative URL" and will use either http or https depending on what the current page is using.  We use these kind of URLs to avoid security prompts warning users that some of the content on the page is not secure.  Your scripts would then look like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//localhost/js/jqueryPlugin.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even doing that I'm getting the same error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit' register.php:431
(anonymous function) register.php:431
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.8.3.js:3058
elemData.handle.eventHandle`

Comment: @Roiw - I'm out of guesses.  If you can reproduce this somewhere like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you a lot man! I will try to figure it out myself. My code was made by an ex-co-worker and there is a bunch of things in my home language and it's a mess. If I manage to find an answer to this I will post here! Thanks a lot for your effort !!!